# Navigation: Can I bind <mat-button-toggle-group> to the app route?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I use an [Angular `<mat-button-toggle-group>`](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview) to drive navigation in my app? Basically, I want the user to click toggle buttons to switch between different routes in a single-page webapp.

I thought this would be simple, but I'm a newcomer to Angular and maybe there's something I'm misunderstanding, or maybe I'm just not searching the correct terms.

The docs have examples of two-way binding connecting the selected toggle button to a domain model property:

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I found [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) but trying to apply it on a `mat-button-toggle` element results in a compiler error:

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-button-toggle'

I guess what I'm looking for (if it exists) is something like:

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group value="page1" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle [routerLink]="/page1">Page1</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle [routerLink]="/page2">Page2</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle [routerLink]="/page3">Page3</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Is there an easy way to have a mat-button-toggle-group for navigation? Or am I doing this wrong and I should just use `<a>` tags and style them as buttons?

Comment: That's the trick, thank you! If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I might write it up myself for somebody else having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you get an error of the following form, it means you're missing an import from Angular in your current module or component:

> error NG0000: Can't bind to 'someAngularDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'some-element'

In your case, the [`routerLink` directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) is exported from [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) via `@angular/router`. Make sure you're importing that module into the module containing your component.

```js
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<a [routerLink]="['/destination']">Go!</a>`,
})
export class MyComponent {}


@NgModule({

  // Import RouterModule since this module declares
  // a component that uses the routerLink directive.
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild()],

  declarations: [MyComponent],
})
export class MyComponentModule {}
```

If you're using standalone components, you might be able to import the `routerLink` directive directly (though you'll have to make sure you have a `Router` instance somewhere in your injection context or the `routerLink` won't know how to route):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink],
  template: `<a [routerLink]="['/destination']">Go!</a>`
})
export class MyStandaloneComponent {}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the imports did fix my problem. I notice your example here shows an `<a>` tag instead of `<mat-button-toggle>`?

Comment: Just for simplicity in the example. The `routerLink` attribute works on nearly every element.

Comment: For some reason adding routerLink to `<mat-button-toggle>` breaks a11y: you can't shift+tab backwards through the buttons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you can use the `routerLink` directive to achieve navigation using `<mat-button-toggle-group>`. Instead of using a domain model property like in the example with font styles, you will bind the `routerLink` to the `value` attribute of each `<mat-button-toggle>` to navigate to different routes in your single-page web app.

Here's how you can use `<mat-button-toggle-group>` for navigation:

1. Import the necessary modules in your component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

2. Create the component and define the routes and their corresponding labels:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  template: `
    <mat-button-toggle-group [value]="selectedRoute">
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="'/page1'" routerLink="/page1">Page 1</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="'/page2'" routerLink="/page2">Page 2</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="'/page3'" routerLink="/page3">Page 3</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  `,
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  selectedRoute = '/page1'; // Set the initial selected route, or you can fetch it based on the current route.
}
```

3. Make sure you have imported the necessary Angular Material modules and declared the `<mat-button-toggle-group>` and `<mat-button-toggle>` components in your app module.
4. Add the `<app-navigation></app-navigation>` component to your app template wherever you want the navigation to appear.

With this setup, when a user clicks on a `<mat-button-toggle>` button, Angular's router will navigate to the specified route defined in the `routerLink` attribute.

Using `<a>` tags with `routerLink` is a common practice for navigation in Angular applications, and it's perfectly fine to use them if you prefer. However, using `<mat-button-toggle-group>` with `routerLink` provides a nice and consistent UI with Material Design styling for your navigation.

Comment: For some reason adding routerLink to `<mat-button-toggle>` breaks a11y: you can't shift+tab backwards through the buttons. Any ideas?